# Anyway to fit this model to these data points?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, curve, data-fitting, model-fitting

I have been tryin to fit these data points to the exponential model *y=ae^(px+qx^2)*. The reason I need this model fit is due to the paper **"Temperature dependence of the functional response" by Göran Englund 2011** where they fit this model on data points as described in one of the figures. I need to fit this with some data I found doing literature review for an ODE model I am working on in my dissertation. However no matter what I do, I cannot fit it using the curvefit() function, even when my guess `p0` is very close. Below is my code and a figure of my fit when I just guessed at the fitted parameters a,p and q until I got a super close fit.

```
k = 0.00008617
def NormalizeData(data):
    return (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))

def C_to_A(C):
    return -1/(k*(C+273))

def model(x, a, p,q):
    return a*np.exp(p*x+q*x**2)

# Input data
x = C_to_A(np.array([11, 11, 11,15,15,15,20,20,20,25,25,25,29,29,29]))
y = NormalizeData(np.array([2.048, 1.56, 1.18, 2.6116,2.35,2.1036,2.97, 2.97, 2.97, 2.463,2.05,1.6679,1.825,1.0939,0.534]))
# do the fit with some initial values
popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, x, y, p0=(9.7*10**-139.95, -16, -0.2))

# prepare some data for a plot
xx = np.linspace(-60, 0)
yy = model(xx, *popt)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xx, yy)
plt.title('Exponential Fit')
plt.ylim(0,1.1)
plt.xlim(-50,32)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
print(popt)
```

If I just plot the model with the data points and my guessed coefficients `a=9.7*10**-139.95, p=-16, q=-0.2` I get the picture below

[image]

Which is super close to what I want. Any suggestions on how I may approach this fit using the model I mentioned? Anything will help!

Comment: You forgot to define `k` in your code.

Comment: @KotaMori Sorry, k = 0.00008617 here. I edited my post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y=ae^(px+qx^2)` implies `log(y) = c + px + qx^2`, where `c=log(a)`,`p`,`q` are parameters. You can estimate the parameters using linear regression of `y` on `x` and `x^2`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.api import OLS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def C_to_A(C, k=0.00008617):
    return -1/(k*(C+273))

# choice of k is arbitrary, change as you wish
x = C_to_A(np.array([11, 11, 11,15,15,15,20,20,20,25,25,25,29,29,29]), k=1)
y = np.array([2.048, 1.56, 1.18, 2.6116,2.35,2.1036,2.97, 2.97, 2.97, 2.463,2.05,1.6679,1.825,1.0939,0.534])


# want to regress log(y) on x, x^2, constant
# create data for this
data = pd.DataFrame({"y":y, "x":x})
data["log_y"] = np.log(data.y)
data["x2"] = data.x**2
data["const"] = 1
data
```

[image]

Estimate the parameters using OLS from statsmodels:

```py
Y = data.log_y
X = data[["x", "x2", "const"]]

ols = OLS(Y, X, hasconst=True).fit()
ols.summary()
```

[image]

For plotting, ols's fitted values property is handy. We convert log(y) to y using exp:

```py
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, np.exp(ols.fittedvalues))
```

[image]